# Can't understand 500: internal error with Django, Apache, Mod_python

Tags: django, apache, mod-python

I'm getting a 500:Internal error when i try to start my apache server with django.
I tried the steps given in the previous questions   [Django with Apache 500 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262164/django-with-apache-500-error) and [Django Apache mod_wsgi 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097155/django-apache-mod-wsgi-500) but neither of them did the trick.

My Wsgi file:

```
    import os
    import sys

    sys.path = ['var/www/first'] + sys.path
    sys.path.append('var/www/first')
    os.eviron['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'first.settings'

    import django.core.handlers.wsgi
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()`
```

My conf file:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   WSGIScriptAlias / /home/alok/Documents/first.wsgi

   Servername website.com
   Alias /static /var/www/first/static/

   <Directory /var/www/first/>

   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all

   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>`
```

I tried changing the permissions to 777 and the folder for wsgi file but still it won't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.eviron` is a typo. You mean `os.environ`.

Your Apache error log probably would have shown you that.

Comment: Oh damn. Thank you so much. I wasted about an hour on this.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't understand why you tried to extend sys.path two times.
2) I think the path should be absolute. **/**var/www/first/
3) Check your ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your.domain/ip-address'] in settings.py file